# Admob in react-native (expo) app not displaying

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I just applied a production ad-unit id for my android app (not published to google play, and I'm testing on my phone and also emulator with product ad-unit-id but the ad don't display, the source code like this

```
// Display a banner
<AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="fullBanner"
  adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" // Test ID, Replace with your-admob-unit-id
  testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
  onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
```

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/admob/

the above code with testing id is displayed in my app (testing on my phone and also emulator), but I use my read key, anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Display a banner
<AdMobBanner
  adSize="fullBanner"
  adUnitID="your-admob-unit-id"
  testDevices={[AdMobBanner.simulatorId]}
  onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
/>
```

put test device id in testDevices which like

testDevices={"sdflhfdshfsdgudsgfuydsgfydsgftysdfdfgsh"}